# HTML tables and mysterious height on several email clients

Tags: html-table, html-email

So I've battled against an HTML email and including Outlook support for some time now. Within the code below Gmail and Outlook both display the `<td>` at 15px in height. Why? Its only meant to be a cross client hr  replacement for a dotted separator line.

```
 <!-- Dotted Horizontal border Outlook Optimized-->
<table style="width:100%;border-bottom:1px dotted #999999;" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tbody align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
         <td style="background:none;height:1px;width:100%;vertical-align:middle;"  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" ></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

UPDATE:
So its because there is an "empty" cell. I thought that an `&nbsp;` would take care of it but more was needed. I also tried putting the 1px image inside the cell as mentioned by @Vitorino Fernandes, the height persisted.

The nbsp does in fact need to exist for several email clients and the use of line-`height:0px;` finally flattened the cell.

Answer (score 1):

as per looking at your code i understand that you are using table to give border -- dont use table because empty table will give some space use td instead and spacer image with height 1px(ad per your border height) and give bg-color to td

or if you want to use the same layout

add a spacer image in the empty td with height 1px and background color- as per your border and give                     line-height:1px to the parent tr

Comment: I would have recommended to use list tags and decorate them as needed with inline styles

Comment: I thought the &nbsp; would have taken care of that for me? So make a transparent image at 1px X 1px and place it in there to force a strict height?